# Cannot find inetmgr in Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Tags: iis-7

I have recently installed Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard in Virtual Machine. I checked by doing localhost in browser as well as created a folder and tested with the link. It works fine. Now I wanted to add PHP extension in IIS7 which says I need to open IIS manager which I don't see either in "Administrative tool" of control panel or I can go from command prompt using "inetmgr".

Comment: Well solved. I have not actually not checked "IIS Management Console" while installing roles from control panel > Administrative tools > Server Manager. I finally checked and added role "IIS Management console" and inetmgr works in run window.

Answer (score 11):

Had the same problem and solved: In Server Manager (open from Administrative Tools), expand Roles, click on Web Server.  Then scroll down to section 'Role Services' and click Add Role Service.  From there you can click the Management Tools section.  Only the Console is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just Write inetmgr in Run window it will showup..
or u need to add / install using Turn on Windows features in Add and Remove Programs
Complete Steps to Install and View IIS is [here Link!!](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-7-and-above-on-windows-server-2008-or-windows-server-2008-r2)

Comment: Dont have inetmgr in run window. Also how do i install IIS from add/remove because it seems it has already been installed in my system as when i run localhost it shows IIS7 home page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you installed Management Tools for IIS. It is server feature called something like "IIS Management Console"

Comment: Please suggest which one? "IIS Management Tools" or "IIS Management Service" or "IIS Management Scripts and Tools". I tried to install with using web platform installer 4.6

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have setup correct roles for Windows server. Also, please make sure that you have installed ,Management Console for your IIS installation.

Below is a useful tutorial given by Microsoft:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771209.aspx

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, `http://localhost` was working but I couldn't get to IIS Manager. Installed "IIS Management Console" and it works!